# How to get the select option value in array

Tags: jquery, select

I am new to jquery I have the following field

```
 <select  name[]="post">
              <option value="op1">op1</option>
              <option value="op2">op2</option>
              <option value="op3">op3</option>
              </option>
 </select>   
 How to get the post[0] & post[1] values in Jquery any Idea 
 .
```

Comment: never seen that notaion name[]="xxx" ar e u sure this is html valid?

Comment: Attribute names cannot have [] in them.

Comment: @helle: it's no valid html. @venkat: what are you trying to archive here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are searching for this...

```
<select name="my_select" id="foo">
              <option value="op1">op1</option>
              <option value="op2">op2</option>
              <option value="op3">op3</option>
              </option>
 </select> 


var options = $('#foo').find('option');
console.log($(options[0]).attr('value'));
```

Comment: unless you have activated the developer tools console...
it will not work in ff, too if you haven't installed firebug ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple select option use the key word "multiple"

```
<select name="my_select" id="foo" multiple>
          <option value="op1">op1</option>
          <option value="op2">op2</option>
          <option value="op3">op3</option>
          </option>
</select>
```

Comment: According to standard, it's: multiple="multiple"

Answer (score 0):

You can get Select's selected value in the following easy ways

```
$('select#your_id').val();

$('select#your_id').children("option:selected").val()

$("select#your_id > option:selected").val()
```

And to get any option on the bases of index, you can use the following

```
$("select#your_id > option:nth-child(1)")
```

Point to note is the index starts from 1-n (0 will return empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="test" id="test">
          <option value="op1">op1</option>
          <option value="op2">op2</option>
          <option value="op3">op3</option>
          </option>
</select>
```

to get the vallue from the select list you can use this piece of code:
**output = $('#test').val();**

```
$('#some_button').click(function()  {
  output = $('#test').val(); 
});
```